# CRM Linq find all parents that have 0 children

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

How can I find (preferably using CRM Linq) parent entities that have 0 children. For example how can I find all accounts that have 0 contacts.

Comment: What you are asking for is pretty simple, but at least care to provide some code, some model, design, check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If it is simple why can I not do it?

Comment: To understand that, post some code and show what you have tried, you certainly cannot expect spoon feeding

Comment: This is a terrible question. Please read [ask] and provide us with something concrete to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the query expression route, which I would recommend then the following code will be useful

```
var entityAlias = "con";
var query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "account",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria =
            { 
                FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression(entityAlias, "contactid",ConditionOperator.Null)
                }
            }
            LinkEntities =
            {
                new LinkEntity
                {
                    EntityAlias = entityAlias,
                    LinkFromEntityName = "account",
                    LinkFromAttributeName = "accountid",
                    LinkToEntityName = "contact",
                    LinkToAttributeName = "parentcustomerid",
                    Columns = new ColumnSet("parentcustomerid", "contactid"),
                    JoinOperator = JoinOperator.LeftOuter,
                }
            },
        };

var response = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
var accounts = response.Entities;
```

In this code I have not limited the columns, this will reduce performance and you should only return the columns needed.

If there is the case for more than 5000 records are going to be returned then you will need to use paging and loop the query to find all the entities, 
This can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx

However if you are certain you want to use LINQ then you can use the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Account> FindAccountsWithNoContacts()
{
   var contactRelationship = new Relationship("contact_customer_accounts");
   foreach(var account in XrmContext.AccountSet)
   {
      XrmContext.LoadProperty(contactRelationship);
      if(!account.RelatedEntities.ContainsKey(contactRelationship)
      yield return account;

   }  
}
```

My problem with the LINQ code is that all the enities, both the account and contact entities, will be loaded into memory. With large entity sets this can cause `OutOfMemoryException`, whereas the query expression route will pass the query to the Dynamics server to execute; which should make the execution of the code faster.

Comment: Agreed, query expression is the more efficient code.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking for is left outer join. Which is unfortunately not possible in CRM using LINQ. However you can do it using query expression or FetchXML.

Here is a link that can help you:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/archive/2014/02/23/all-about-outer-join-queries-in-crm-2011-and-crm-2013

Comment: You are 100% correct I am struggling because there is no left outer join in Linq CRM. I was hoping for a linq to crm solution but fetch will do. THanks

Comment: Is `Left Outer Join` only way to figure out children, no other `Linq APIs` help ?

Comment: @user3845056 if you are satisfied with the my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer. thanks.